# Create a bounding box from two points with a customizable width

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, console-application

I have two points making a line, I want to see if a point is ruffly on the line. To do this I need to create a bounding box/ a rectangle which has a width D outwards/ perpendicular to the line. I was following this [website for guidance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502026/creating-a-bounding-box-for-2-points-with-a-custimizable-width) but seem to have implemented it wrongly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  private static bool IsInside(GPS Point1, GPS Point2)
        {
            GPS VectorV = new GPS()
            {
                Longitude = Point1.Longitude - Point2.Longitude,
                Latitude = Point1.Latitude - Point2.Latitude
            };

            GPS VectorW = new GPS()
            {
                Longitude = -1 / VectorV.Longitude,
                Latitude = -1 / VectorV.Latitude
            };

            double W = Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(VectorW.Latitude * VectorW.Latitude) + Convert.ToDouble(VectorW.Longitude * VectorW.Longitude));

            GPS NewVector = new GPS()
            {
                Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDouble(VectorW.Longitude) / W),
                Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDouble(VectorW.Latitude) / W),
            };

            decimal D = 5;

            GPS DisplacmentVector = new GPS()
            {
                Longitude = (D / 2) * NewVector.Longitude,
                Latitude = (D / 2) * NewVector.Latitude
            };

            GPS BPoint1 = new GPS() { Longitude = Point1.Longitude + DisplacmentVector.Longitude, Latitude = Point1.Latitude + DisplacmentVector.Latitude };
            GPS BPoint2 = new GPS() { Longitude = Point1.Longitude - DisplacmentVector.Longitude, Latitude = Point1.Latitude - DisplacmentVector.Latitude };
            GPS BPoint3 = new GPS() { Longitude = Point2.Longitude + DisplacmentVector.Longitude, Latitude = Point2.Latitude + DisplacmentVector.Latitude };
            GPS BPoint4 = new GPS() { Longitude = Point2.Longitude - DisplacmentVector.Longitude, Latitude = Point2.Latitude - DisplacmentVector.Latitude };
}

 public partial class GPS
    {
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }

        public GPS() { }

        public GPS(decimal longitude, decimal latitude) {
            Longitude = longitude;
            Latitude = latitude;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just calculate the distance from the point to the line and see if it's within your "ruffly" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a vector `v= A to B = {xb-xa, yb-ya} = {vx, vy}` there are two directions for its perpendicular: one heading right of A->B, the orther heading left of A->B.

One perpendicular vector is `w1= {-vy, vx}` (towards left), the other is `w2= {vy, -vx}` (towards right). Note than `w1 = -w2`.

To get the four corners you may use w1 or w2 or both. It's a matter of the used signs and the order of resultant points.

Let's use `w1`. Your definition is wrong. Use this instead:

```
GPS VectorW = new GPS()
{
    Longitude = - VectorV.Latitude,
    Latitude =  VectorV.Longitude
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things. There are 3 cases for the line:

> 1. Line parallel with x axis (y coordinate of both points are equal), easy to calculate
> 2. Line parallel with y axis (x coordinate of both points are equal), easy to calculate

for the rest you need dx and dy:

```
cos(θ) = dx / (D / 2) => dx = cos(θ) * (D / 2)
sin(θ) = dy / (D / 2) => dy = sin(θ) * (D / 2)

θ = 90 - φ
tan(φ) = a / b => φ = atan(a / b)
```

[image]

Thats it.

Comment: Can this be further simplified to `atan2(a, b)`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to go for a different approach and instead found the distance away from the line the point was. It follows the same logic that it must be X distance away from the line.

[For guidance I followed/ used this code.](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/09/find-the-shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment-in-c/)